# Rails sharing login across subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, devise

So I have two rails apps on the same domain, which both use `devise` and `ldap` to authenticate to the same ldap server.

To store the cookie as cross session I changed both apps;

`config\initializers\session_store.rb`:

```
MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_bioinf_exp_session', :expire_after => 2.hours, :domain => '.domain.com'
```

What this does is produce an: `actioncontroller::invalidauthenticitytoken` error in `Devise::SessionsController`.

Googling around I found that I needed to have the same secret keys in `config\initializers\secret_store.rb`. However, this didn't remove the problem.

I then tried giving the `config.secret_key` in `devise.rb` the same value across both apps, but the same error remains.

If someone could explain which parts I missing/misunderstanding that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Once I had faced this when I was doing PHP... A not so elegant solution I had used was to store my sessions on a table, accessible from both apps. Negative impact: storing session on DB is the slowest mechanism...

Comment: Yes, that's my backup plan if I can't find a better solution :)

Comment: @Darkstarone, I have done a setup you're fighting with. It was authlogic instead of devise, but the idea was the same. Having sessions in db is generally a bad idea since it needs cyclic vacuum.

Comment: @Darkstarone, what's the result for `:domain => :all`?

Comment: Both the sites work (no authentication problems), but they still require separate sign ons.

Comment: IF I additionally add `:tld_length => 2` I get: `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`